# How to send information and receive from an website trough xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, button, web, uitextfield

How can i send information and receive information from a website without "downloading" the file once and then using it. Like, every time I push on a button, i could receive what the text on the website is trough the code, and not by UIWebView.

And also, if i have a textfield, i could type some text in and then push at a button, and send this text to the website, in some kind of way.

Could someone give me an example of this?

By the way, sorry for my english. Let me know if it was something you didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSString has a method `+ (id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error` that you can use for grabbing text in a very simple way. To upload the text you could use NSURLRequest together with NSURLConnection.

There are also this framework that might do stuff you'd like: http://restkit.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSURLConnection for grabbing stuff from HTML requests.  You can [read the Apple documentation on NSURLConnection here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).